# Descendent Gromov-Witten invariants and Frobenius manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, gromov-witten-theory, frobenius-algebras

I've heard it said that genus $0$ descendent Gromov-Witten invariants of a smooth projective variety $X$ can be encoded in the structure of a Frobenius manifold on the cohomology $H^*(X,\mathbb{C)}$. I am very confused by this - it is clear that this is true for non-descendent Gromov-Witten invariants. How do the descendent invariants enter in?